# Connection must be valid and open

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using a method which get me a list of items from database. I already used the connection to insert data to database and works fine, but when displaying data in gridview an exception pops up. Below you can find the method used, the code for binding data to gridview and the asp for the gridview. Hope you can help. Thanks

Method to retreive data

```
public List<Bet> getBets()
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM bets ORDER BY date");

            try
            {
                if (this.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    this.Connection.Open();

                MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection); --> getting exception here
                List<Bet> bets = new List<Bet>();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Bet myBet = new Bet();
                    myBet = FillBetfromRow(dr);
                    bets.Add(myBet);
                }
                return bets;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    Connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Binding data to gridview

```
gvBets.DataSource = new BetManagement().getBets();
            gvBets.DataBind();
```

Comment: and what is the exception? Your title?

Comment: _"Hope you can help me"_  - not if you don't explain the problem. From the title I guess you get an exception? Please capture the full exception description. Then do a web search on it. If you then can't find a solution, edit your question to incorporate the exception,  show at what line it occurs and explain what you have tried.

Comment: Why do you ask a question here when you got the Errormessage already? Try to debug through your code. I guess your Connection Object might contain the Wrong Connectionstring or might be in an inconsistent state

Comment: Yes this is the exception: Connection must be valid and open. I am getting this exception in this code MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing with Using Keyword. There may be an issue with the data reader close

```
 try
        {
            if (this.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                this.Connection.Open();
            List<Bet> bets = new List<Bet>();
            using(MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)){


            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Bet myBet = new Bet();
                myBet = FillBetfromRow(dr);
                bets.Add(myBet);
            }
       }
            return bets;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you didn't set a `Connection` in your `Command` object.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM bets ORDER BY date");
cmd.Connection = this.Connection;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just close Datareader after while loop ,like dr.close() ,and assign connection con to your command

Comment: Yes this is the exception: Connection must be valid and open.

I am getting this exception in this code MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

Comment: cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM bets ORDER BY date",con); after that write MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();